# Calculate best-case, average-case and worst-cae algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have following algorithm and I need to calculate best-case, worst-case and average-case complexity of it:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++){
    for (j=0; j<N; j++){
        if  ((tab[i][j] % 2 != 0) && (tab[j][i] % 2 != 0)){
            tab[i][i] += tab [i][j] + tab[j][i];
        }
    }
}
```

The question is - do I count ifs (as one or two - because there are two operations inside) or only alignments?
I guess complexity is **n^2**, but I don't know how to calculate best-case, worst-case and average-case complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is N^2 in every case. The actual number of operations is somewhere between (c*N^2, C*N^2) where c, C are constants, c < C. The actual number of operations differ in worst, best and average cases but that doesn't change the quadratic nature of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is asymptotic. So, O(c*n) is taken as O(n) where c is a constant. If you want to calculate the actual number of operations, then for example, in the i loop:

Initialization of i is one operation.

i < N comparison occurs N+1 times

i++ increment operation occurs N times.

So, the loop itself has 2*N+2 operations plus the operations in the loop n times.